# Looking for corresponding intervals for points

Tags: python, loops, search, intervals

I have 5 tuples `A, B, C, D` and `E` representing intervals. Their intersection is empty (for each pair of them) and they are sort such as the upper limit of one interval is smaller than the lower limit of the following interval.

For example:

```
A = (5, 10)
B = (21, 29)
C = (134, 160)
D = (900, 1050)
E = (1080, 1100)

intervals = [A, B, C, D, E]
```

I also have a list `X` of points sorted in increasing order.

For example:

```
X = [6, 28, 130, 1000, 1129]
```

As you can see, each one of the numbers in `X` can or cannot belong to one interval. Since the intervals intersection is empty, each number can belong to at most one interval.
**Besides, by construction, only one number per interval.**

I'm trying to know to which interval does every number in `X` belongs, if any.
So for my example, the ouput should be:

```
output = [(6, A), (28, B), (None, C), (1000, D), (None, E)]
```

which means that the numbers `6, 28, 1000` belong to intervals `A, B, D` respectively, and no number belongs to intervals `C` and `E`.

In order to find to which interval does every number in `X` belongs to, I did the following:

```
output = []
for interval in intervals:
    for number in X:
        if interval[0] <= number and number <= interval[1]:
            found_interval = True
            output.append((number, interval))
            break

    if not found_interval:
        output.append((None, interval))
```

This should work, but I thought that there should be a faster way. I would like to avoid having to loop over the `X` for each interval. An upgraded solution would loop over the remaining numbers who hadn't found any interval.

**Is there a faster way of doing this?**

Comment: In your notation you are using open intervals like (5,10) -which would exclude end points but in your code you use <=, which would correspond to closed intervals (such as [5,10]) which would include their endpoints. Which is it? Also -- is it always the case that the right endpoint of one interval is less than the left endpoint of the next? (That is automatic from what you said if they are closed intervals but not open ones)

Comment: @John: I think that the notation is Python syntax, not open/closed interval notation.  Tomas, is this correct?

Comment: Are there only five intervals, or do you need to expand this to a large set?  If it's only 5, then there is little to gain by using a fancier algorithm, even if it's faster.

Comment: You can delete the found interval from intervals once you've place a point within it; that's your "upgraded solution".

Comment: @JohnColeman It is the Python syntax for tuple, not the mathematic notation for open interval.

Comment: @Prune Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Prune There should be around 10 intervals and around the same amount of points in X. I am looking for a fancier algorithm since I will be running it inside another two big `for` loops (which I didn't put in the question because it has nothing to do). I'm trying to go faster everywhere that is possible.

Comment: @tomasyany -- that is what I thought, but I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look-up the intersections for this problem in linear time:

- Create two variables to track the current value and interval indices.
- As long as you haven't gone over every element in either list, check
  if the current value belongs to the interval.
- **If the value belongs to the current interval**, increase by one **both the current value and current interval indices**.
  Since both the values and the intervals are sorted and the intervals are non-overlapping, **no other element can belong to the current interval**, so we can safely move along.
- **If the value is less than the current interval's lower bound**, increase the current value index, as the value cannot belong to any interval with a larger lower bound either.
- **If the value is greater than the current interval's upper bound**, increase the current interval index, as any other value would be greater than this bound as well.

  ```
  def find_intersection(values, intervals):
      output = []
      value_index = 0
      interval_index = 0

      while value index < len(values) and interval_index < len(intervals):
          current_value = values[value_index]
          current_interval = intervals[interval_index]
          lower_bound, upper_bound = current_interval

          if current_value < lower_bound:
              output.append((None, current_value))
              # This value cannot belong to any greater interval.
              value_index += 1
          elif current_value > upper_bound:
              # No other value can belong to this interval either.
              interval_index += 1
          else:
              output.append((current_interval, current_value))
              # At most one value per interval and one interval per value.
              value_index += 1
              interval_index += 1

      # If we ran out of intervals all remaining values do not belong to any.
      for v in values[value_index:]:
          output.append((None, v))

      return output
  ```

Worst case scenario, no number belongs to any interval and we have to iterate each list completely (`intervals` in the while loop and `values` in the for loop), so the complexity is `O(n + m)`, where `n` is the number of values and `m` that of intervals.

Comment: Nice, elegant solution.

Comment: I had accepted @JohnColeman answer, but this is even better (even John thinks that is a nice solution!). So I changed the accepted answer for this one.

Comment: @tomasyany fine with me -- but note that if you get to a situation where n is much smaller than m then the O(n log m) might be preferable to O(n+m), so it is good to keep both approaches in mind and pick the one which is best for your particular problem.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, thanks for noting that. I had thought of the same, but for the given situation `n` and `m` should have very similar sizes.

Answer (score 2):

[On Edit: my original code didn't handle the case where `x` is one of the right endpoints correctly. The revised code fixes that, with the test examples extended to show how it handles other edge cases]

Maybe this will help: Create a list of all endpoints in sorted order like

```
ends = [5,10,21,29,134,160,900,1050,1080,1100]
```

and use the `bisect` module to find where a point, x, lies in this list. This is a binary search hence is more efficient than your linear search. If it falls between two indices (i-1,i) where i is odd then x is in the corresponding interval. Otherwise it is in none.

Also, it is easy enough to use your list of tuples `intervals` to load up the sorted list of endpoints:

```
from bisect import bisect

def place(x,endpoints):
    i = bisect(endpoints,x)
    if i%2 == 0:
        if x == endpoints[i-1]:
            return endpoints[i-1],endpoints[i]
        else:
            return None
    else:
        return endpoints[i-1],endpoints[i]

A = (5, 10)
B = (21, 29)
C = (134, 160)
D = (900, 1050)
E = (1080, 1100)

intervals = [A, B, C, D, E]

ends = []
for interval in intervals:
    ends.extend(interval)

xs = [3, 5, 6, 10, 28, 130, 1000, 1129]

for x in xs:
    print(str(x),':',str(place(x,ends)))
```

Output:

```
3 : None
5 : (5, 10)
6 : (5, 10)
10 : (10, 21)
28 : (21, 29)
130 : None
1000 : (900, 1050)
1129 : None
```

Comment: I'm not very sure about what does the bisect method do. I will look for it and calculate this algorithm complexity, and comment back.

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind if the set of endpoints was large enough; thanks for completing the example!

Comment: don't bother with theoretical complexity, just use %timeit

Comment: @tomasyany Binary search is `O(log(n))` compared to your `O(n)` linear search. I also added some code to take your list of intervals and create the sorted list of endpoints, though doubtless an elegant comprehension could do it in just 1 line.

Comment: @JulienBernu Yes and no. It for academic purposes, and therefore it is important for me to understand the complexity. Besides, since I don't know yet the exact size of the intervals list, etc., I prefer to trust mathematics. That been said, I will defintely use %timeit at the end and compare.

Comment: @JohnColeman Although I couldn't found the way that the insertion point is computed by `bisect`, I guess it is as you said in `O(log(n))` with binary search (seams logic), and therefore faster than my method, and I think that this might be even faster than my "upgraded method". Maybe an even faster way would be to remove found intervals from `ends` on each loop (kind of upgrade to your method).

Comment: I will wait a little bit before accepting this as an answer, just in case someone comes up with an even faster solution.

Comment: Tough the complexity of the place method is logarithmic, the overall complexity is loglinear (O(n * log(n))). The original solution is O(n^2).

Comment: @Patbenavente Yes, that's what we meant. Since both algorithms were `O(n * search_algorithm_complexity)` the important thing was to go faster in the search, and that's what John and I put when talking about complexity. Besides, if you want to be even more precise, it would be `O(m * log(n))` where `m` is the size of `X`  and `n` the size of `intervals`.

Comment: @tomasyany By the problem statement: _each number can belong to at most one interval.
Besides, by construction, **only one number per interval**._ So `n = m`.

Comment: @Patbenavente I read "only one number per interval" as meaning "not more than one" but leaving open the possibility of 0. There are numbers which belong to no intervals and also intervals which contain no numbers in OP's description, especially as edited, so I'm not sure how you can infer that m = n.